# Set ping_timeout with ssl on Flask-ScoketIO

Tags: python, gevent, flask-socketio

I´m trying to run flask-socketIO + Gevent with this config:

App.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    socketio.run(
        flask_app,
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port=5000, 
        ping_timeout =  10 * 60 * 1000,
        keyfile='key.pem',
        certfile='cert.pem',
    )
```

But I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXX\anaconda3\envs\atrio\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 233, in wrap_socket_and_handle
    with _closing_socket(self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)) as ssl_socket:
TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ping_timeout'
```

Is there any other way to send change ping_timeout value?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the options that apply to the web server with the options that apply to Socket.IO.

The `ping_interval` applies to Socket.IO. You can pass it when you create your `SocketIO()` object, or if you prefer, in the `socketio.init_app()` call.

Side note: `ping_interval` values are given in seconds, not milliseconds. Also, for 99+% of applications the default value is the optimal one, so I recommend that you don't change it.